# NodeJs - Socket.io, Can't access socket.io.js trough js file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I want to access socket.io.js trough an external js file (in my case called script.js), but I am getting the following error when trying to access trough the client side js file.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined
```

But when using js inside of my html it works fine.
My Node.js API serves socket.io.js correctly and is accessable.
Following html code works without errors.

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        const socket = io();
        socket.on('message', function (message) {
        console.log(message);
        });

    </script>
</script>
```

While external js code doesn't work

```
const socket = io();
socket.on('message', function (message) {
console.log(message);
});
```

All js file are linked in head of my html

Answer (score 0):

I'm kinda dump found my mistake called my script.js in header before socket.io.js